# Shard-Folder in Virtualbox is not displayed on the VM

Tags: virtualbox

I installed the guest extension for virtualbox and created a folder in the started vm (Windows 11) via --> Devices --> Shared Folder -->. The Shared folder is /home/i-M/desk/my_shard_folder under linux. I then restarted the VM-Windows. The shared folder should now be displayed in the MS-Windows VM. Unfortunately, this is not the case. What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install in the VM the

```
VBox Windows Additions
```

Devices --> Use guest extensions